# Own command works not with all LaTeX distributions and LaTeX document classes

Tags: errors, distributions

A new defined command (see below) works on my windows with MiKTeX 2.9 and on a Mac with MacTeX.
On another windows (running in a Mac) with an absolute fresh installed MiKTeX and on the same Mac in Mac OS with MacTeX the command doesn't work.

We are using absolutely the same files.
The scrartcl class is used in there.

The command:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \sectionmark{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
}
```

The Error Message on the failing distributions (when the command is called):

```
Argument of \XKV@d@fine@k@y has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \mysection{Die rationalen Zahlen $\Qe_0^+$}
```

### Update

I updated all my Packages via MiKTeX update manager and get the error now, too.
I created a MWE. Interesting is that it works with class article, but not with scrartcl:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \sectionmark{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mysection{test}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 \mysection{test}
```

Comment: You are not using absolutly the same files. So check carefully the log for differences.

Comment: The error message is from xkeyval (which had some updates this year) but the code you show is not obviously using that) please always post a complete small document that demonstrates the error, not just a fragment

Comment: with the new MWE I get (texlive 2014)  `! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
` what error do you see with miktex

Comment: @David Carlisle: I added the Error message in the question.

Comment: yes that's what I get so whatever it is it's an unrelated error to the one you put in the initial question (which was about xkeyval package)

Comment: Indeed, the error in the initial question was on a Mac machine running windows using a fresh install of MiKTeX. The new error is on my machine, after I updated my packages. I have no idea why.

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
\listfiles
```

to your document and compare the package versions listed on the two machines. Update any packages that are out of sync (`xkeyval` most likely given the error message).

The MWE you added shows a missing `\protect`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
   \sectionmark{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\mysection{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I made an update now for my packages via miktex update manager.
Now I get the same error message. So the next question is, what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I created a MWE in my original question above.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Is it possible to describe in a few words, why it is neccessary here?

Comment: @RafaelWörner \protect is always needed in arguments that are written to external commands except for "robust" commands that are defined to add \protect automatically